# how to solve this profit and loss problem

Tags: problem-solving

Xavier buys an apple from Yahoo for Rs.5 and sells it to Zoe for Rs.10. He later buys the apple back from Zoe for Rs.12 and sells back to Yahoo for Rs.15. What is his profit over venture?

Comment: $-5+10-12+15=$ Rs. $8$

Comment: Xavier spent $17$ and received $25$ so $25-17=8$

Comment: thank you.......